# GDB does not load debugging symbols although they are present

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc, gdb, debug-symbols

I have a binary which was compiled with gcc and debugging symbols enabled:

```
# file binary
binary: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=f5902695bdca690e84987fb377b69d16e3b47829, not stripped
```

Using `objdump -syms binary` I can also see the debugging symbols. However, GDB does not load them when I run `gdb ./binary`:

```
Reading symbols from ./binary...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) list
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

Why is this happening and how can I load the debugging symbols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this happening and how can I load the debugging symbols?

This is most likely happening because in fact the library does *not* have debugging symbols.

> `file binary`
>   `... not stripped`

Above output does *not* indicate that the binary has debugging symbols, only that it has a symbol table. So does this: `objdump -syms`.

To *really* see debugging symbols, do this: `readelf -wi binary` (I predict you wouldn't see any).

If debug symbols are in fact present, you should see something like this:

```
$ readelf -wi ./a.out
Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0x4e (32-bit)
   Version:       4
   Abbrev Offset: 0x0
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x5): GNU C11 7.3.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g
    <10>   DW_AT_language    : 12   (ANSI C99)
    <11>   DW_AT_name        : t.c
    <15>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): /tmp
    <19>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x5fa
    <21>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0xb
    <29>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0
 <1><2d>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <2e>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <2e>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x33): main
    <32>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <33>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1
    <34>   DW_AT_type        : <0x4a>
    <38>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x5fa
    <40>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0xb
    <48>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c     (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
    <4a>   DW_AT_GNU_all_call_sites: 1
 <1><4a>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_base_type)
    <4b>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 4
    <4c>   DW_AT_encoding    : 5    (signed)
    <4d>   DW_AT_name        : int
 <1><51>: Abbrev Number: 0
```